# Solution of a first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $$ \frac{dy} {dx}  = \left(\frac{x+2y-3}{2x+y+3}\right)^2  $$

The answer is given as: $$ (x+3)^3 -  (y+3)^3 = c(x-y+6)^4$$

My attempt :I tried to expand the terms in the numerator and the denominator, arrange them into differentials and then integrate then, but I couldn't arrange all the terms in integrable format. Any suggestion to solve this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Let $x=u+a$ and $y=v+b$ then
\begin{cases}
x+2y-3=u+a+2v+2b-3,\\
2x+y+3=2u+2a+v+b+3.
\end{cases}
and find $a$ and $b$ such that
\begin{cases}
a+2b-3=0,\\
2a+b+3=0.
\end{cases}
With this substitution you have a homogeneous differential equation and solve that with $w=\dfrac{u}{v}$ substitution.